# Colour coded data, how do I use VBA to separate them?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file containing data that are colour coded in batches i.e. Cell B2:B10 Red, Cell B11:B20 Blue, Cell B30:31 Red. The cells between these batches are not coloured. I would like to separate these rows and put them in a separate worksheet. The problem is that I not only want to get the values in the colored column but the entire row

So, I'll need to loop across the column, and select the first range that is coloured Red. Then copy those value into a new sheet. Then move on to the next colour (blue), and then copy it into another sheet.

Is this possible? How can I find out the color code of a cell?

[image: An example of how my data looks like]

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no way to find out the colorindex, but if you know the colors and only have these two colors it is possible. In this case you can just use this code and change the colorindexes to whatever your codes are, but you'll need two new sheets which are named "red" and "blue". In this example I used the colorindexes 3 for red and 5 for blue.

```
Sub color()
i = 0
b = 0
r = 0
Do While ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(i + 1, 2).Interior.ColorIndex <> xlNone
    Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(i + 1, 2).Value
    If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(i + 1, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 5 Then
        b = b + 1
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("blue").Cells(b, 1).Value = Value
    ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(i + 1, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
        r = r + 1
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("red").Cells(r, 1).Value = Value
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello there, thank you for your input. 

I'm actually more interested to know how to select the range themselves 

So for example, since my data is color coded Cell B2:B10 Red, Cell B11:B20 Blue, Cell B30:31 Red, only that column is colour coded but I will need the data from different columns as well but of the same rows. 

i.e. Cell C2:C10,C11:C20, E2:E10. I apologize if my question is too vague. 

I've also tested out your code but it doesn't seem to take into account the non-coloured cells in between the rows. I think I have a lot to learn in coding. Sorry!

Comment: @faiezin I didnt use select bc it is way slower with big amounts of data. Are there gaps in the list or do you know how long it is? And where should the uncolored cells go? Do you only need columns B to E?

Comment: I've attached an example of how my data looks like. Some batches immediately starts after the previous one. And some there are downtime in between the batches. But there are no empty spaces in between them. 

As you can see, only one column is colour coded. But I need the range of the row to work with. There are also other worksheets but they also correspond to the same row. I only need feed flowrate, air flowrate and humidity (Columns B,C and E in the example). 

There are about 3000 rows in my workbook. I apologize for not providing the actual data as it is confidential.